# SQL Server LAG() function to calculate differences between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, datediff, date-difference

I'm new in SQL Server and I've got some doubts about the lag() function.
I have to calculate the average distance (in days) between two user's activities. Then, I have to GROUP BY all the users, calculate all the date differences between rows for each user, and finally select the average of the group.

Just to be clear, I've got this kind of table:
[image: original table]

---

First I have to filter days with activities (activities!=0). Then I have to create this:

[image: calculate differences between rows]

And finally, the expected outcome is this one:

[image: what i want]

I thought this could be a "kind of" code:

```
select userid, avg(diff)
  (SELECT *,DATEDIFF(day, Lag(dateid, 1) OVER(ORDER BY [Userid]), 
   dateid) as diff
   FROM table1
   where activities!=0
   group by userid) t
group by userid
```

Of course it doesn't work. I think I also have to do a while loop since rownumber changes for each users.

I hope you can help meeee! thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Rather than posting data as images, many of the volunteers here would much more prefer you supply it as `text`. If you want to be really helpful, DDL and `INSERT` statements are even better([How to post T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)). Some of the data in your picture looks like it's missing (where is the value for activities on the 3rd row in the first image, for example). I also can't see how the data from the first image becomes the data in the second. If you supply DDL & `INSERT` statements it'll be very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there. Just add `partition by userid` so the difference is calculated for each userid and `order by dateid`.

```
select userid, avg(diff)
  (SELECT t.*
         ,DATEDIFF(day, Lag(dateid, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY [Userid] ORDER BY [dateid]),dateid) as diff
   FROM table1 t
   where wager!=0
  ) t
group by userid
```

Comment: Thanks Vamsi! At the moment I can't see if it works but I will let you know!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `lag()` at all.  The average is the maximum minus the minimum divided by one less than the count:

```
SELECT userid,
       DATEDIFF(day, MIN(dateid), MAX(dateid)) * 1.0 / NULLIF(COUNT(*), 1) as avg_diff
FROM table1
WHERE wager<> 0
GROUP BY userid;
```