# Calculate the difference between rows using LAG()

Tags: mysql

This question is similar to [SQL Server LAG() function to calculate differences between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220109/sql-server-lag-function-to-calculate-differences-between-rows), except that that example uses `DATEDIFF()`. Suppose I have a table `Weather` with columns `RecordDate` and `Temperature`. I'd like to select the rows corresponding to `Temperature`s that are higher than on the previous day.

So for example, if `Weather` is like this,

```
mysql> select * from weather;
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | RecordDate | Temperature |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  5 | 2000-12-16 |           3 |
|  6 | 2000-12-15 |          -1 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

I'd like to select the second day,

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | RecordDate | Temperature |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  5 | 2000-12-16 |           3 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

because the temperature of `3` on that day is higher than that of `-1` on the previous day.

I feel like with this query, which follows the example at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag, I'm almost there:

```
mysql> select id, recorddate, temperature, 
              lag(temperature) over w as 'lag' 
       from weather 
       window w as (order by recorddate);
+----+------------+-------------+------+
| id | recorddate | temperature | lag  |
+----+------------+-------------+------+
|  6 | 2000-12-15 |          -1 | NULL |
|  5 | 2000-12-16 |           3 |   -1 |
+----+------------+-------------+------+
```

what remains is to select the rows where `temperature` is greater than `lag`. However, if I add `where temperature > lag` to the end of the query, I get a syntax error:

```
mysql> select id, recorddate, temperature, 
              lag(temperature) over w as 'lag' 
       from weather 
       window w as (order by recorddate) 
       where temperature > lag;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'where temperature > lag' at line 1

Is there any way to maintain only the rows where `temperature > lag` in this intermediate result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is utilizing [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) (which would work in older versions of MySQL as well). We can use the subquery to get the previous temperature for every row based on the previous date, and then using `HAVING` clause to filter out the cases where the current temperature is higher than the previous temperature:

**Query #1**

```
SELECT w1.id, w1.recorddate, w1.temperature, 
       (SELECT w2.temperature 
        FROM weather AS w2 
        WHERE w2.RecordDate < w1.RecordDate 
        ORDER BY w2.RecordDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev_temperature 
FROM weather AS w1
HAVING w1.temperature > prev_temperature;

| id  | recorddate | temperature | prev_temperature |
| --- | ---------- | ----------- | ---------------- |
| 5   | 2000-12-16 | 3           | -1               |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ibLzfDXgcTwSChwPnmt4wU/1)

---

**MySQL 8+ only:** We can still solve this problem using [`LAG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) function, but not in a straightforward manner. As of now, MySQL complains if we try to use a Window function, in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT id, RecordDate, temperature 
FROM weather 
WHERE temperature > LAG(temperature) OVER (ORDER BY RecordDate);
```

> Error: You cannot use the window function 'lag' in this context.

OR, if we try to calculate the previous temperature in an expression, and use the alias in `HAVING` clause to filter:

```
SELECT id, RecordDate, temperature, 
       LAG(temperature) OVER (ORDER BY RecordDate) AS prev_temperature 
FROM weather 
HAVING temperature > prev_temperature;
```

> Error: You cannot use the alias 'prev_temperature' of an expression
>   containing a window function in this context.

So, one option available to us is to calculate all the previous temperature values for every row, and use this subquery as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), to filter out in outer `Select` query.

**Query #2**

```
SELECT dt.*
FROM   (SELECT id,
               RecordDate,
               temperature,
               Lag(temperature) OVER w AS prev_temperature
        FROM   weather
        WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY RecordDate)) AS dt
WHERE  dt.temperature > dt.prev_temperature;

| id  | RecordDate | temperature | prev_temperature |
| --- | ---------- | ----------- | ---------------- |
| 5   | 2000-12-16 | 3           | -1               |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ibLzfDXgcTwSChwPnmt4wU/2)

Comment: You are right, there is of course the issue of not being able to use a window function in a where/having clause. Your answer covers it nicely.