# SQL - calculate total value of group, row by row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a fact sales table that is structured like the below. This contains information on subscriptions (sales) by customer.

| CustomerKey | SubscriptionKey | StartDate | End date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 385884 | 1256 | 2020-01-17 00:00:00.000 | 2025-06-17 00:00:00.000 | 200 |
| 385884 | 2346 | 2020-03-11 00:00:00.000 | 2022-06-10 00:00:00.000 | 400 |
| 385884 | 5433 | 2022-10-17 00:00:00.000 | 2024-07-17 00:00:00.000 | 500 |

I want to add a row which shows me at the time of end date, the total value of a customer so the business can use the total value to determine whether the customer is worth renewing or not. So based on the above table it would look like this..

| CustomerKey | SubscriptionKey | StartDate | End date | Value | ValueAtEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 385884 | 1256 | 2020-01-17 00:00:00.000 | 2025-06-17 00:00:00.000 | 200 | 200 |
| 385884 | 2346 | 2020-03-11 00:00:00.000 | 2022-06-10 00:00:00.000 | 400 | 600 |
| 385884 | 5433 | 2022-10-17 00:00:00.000 | 2024-07-17 00:00:00.000 | 500 | 700 |

So what it needs to do is look at "active" subscription by CustomerKey.. and then calculate the total value of any active subscriptions at the time of **[End date]**. This is done if the **[End fate]** falls between the **[startdate]** and end date of another subscription associated to that contract.

I have tried the method below but really can't get my head around the best way of even approaching this.. so any tips or just pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

[SQL Server LAG() function to calculate differences between rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220109/sql-server-lag-function-to-calculate-differences-between-rows)

Image example of below solution..
[image]

Comment: I looked at running total.. but I thought this was just used to calculate the running total of items in order.. whereas my example has a subscription date range that surpasses the other 2 for that customer.. so I am not sure how I could make this work? I have used running totals before to calculate total payments by month running total that was pretty simple.. just not sure how I would make the same thing work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from T t1 cross apply (
    select sum(Value) from T t2
    where t2.CustomerKey = t1.CustomerKey
        and t1.EndDate between t2.StartDate and t2.EndDate
) v(ValueAtEndDate);
```

This could be just a scalar subquery. Either way is essentially the same.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa500f79e17b5681410f1e6ce8464551

Comment: This works and is so simple... took me a good while to actually understand what it's doing but a good lesson to learn.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scalar subquery to compute the extra column. For example:

```
select t.*,
  t.value + (
    select sum(value)
    from t u
    where u.end_date between t.startdate and t.enddate 
      and u.susbscriptionkey <> t.susbscriptionkey 
      and u.customerkey = t.customerkey
  ) as vaed
from t
```

Comment: I looked at this.. looks like it works but then if you look at the image attached to my original post... the last row should actually show as 32000.00 as no other contracts would be active on 17th feb 2021.. so it shouldn't be adding any of the other values to this row